# Neural Network Architecture to approximate simple function

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, lstm, machine-learning-model

What neural network architecture would approximate this function? This is monotonically decreasing non negative time series, that has non-stationary mean.

$$
q(t) = \frac{qi}{(1+b*D*t)^(\frac{1}{b})}.
$$

Currently, I have a function to generate a time series of $q(t)$ as a function of $ qi , b ,D $ at any given time $ t $ . I use this function to generate many sequences varying the parameters of $ qi , b ,D $ for a set of times. So my synthetic data looks like $ q(1),q(2)...q(n)$ I then split that data in a train period and test period of different lengths: $ [q(1)...q(m)][q(m+1)...q(n)]$  I am attempting to train a neural network on this synthetic data, so I have essentially unlimited training data.

I have tried MLP, LSTM, CONV-LSTM, but don't have a clear sense of how many layers/neurons are needed for this task. I have tried a few layers with 30-60 neurons in each. It is not clear how much synthetic data I need to generate also and over 100,000 in single model fit slows down training significantly.

Does anyone have any advice how to approach this problem?

Comment: LSTMs are best if you are trying to model any type of time-series data. Also, you will need to put some dense layers on top of your LSTM layer(s), and since its a regression style problem your output layer should be of shape - N * 1(N being the size of the previous dense layer). Choose linear activation and mean_squared_error loss. I suppose you did most of it.

Comment: Choose the Maximum Sequence Length very carefully, basically how many timesteps you feeding to the model to get t+1. Various time series modes give you this information that to effectively measure t+1 exactly how many time steps in the past you need to look. You could use those to get optimum sequence length in your case

Comment: So my initial though was to use an encoder-decoder structure since the physical equation only contains 3 variables, so ideally I would encode the input to denser representation then decode to any variable length? Does this seem reasonable? You mention adding dense layers, would i need to add more dense layers then just the output? My sequence length is 60 inputs and 300 outputs.

Comment: I was coming from the fact that you already had generated a lot of sequences using the function and would try to predict t+1 given t and so on.

In the encoder-decoder architecture too you will need to generate these sequences and here instead of generating one timestep at a time your decoder can give out arbitrary number of outputs.

Comment: I mentioned dense layers and the last dense layer in the decoder to be a single output one because you are trying model continuous outputs. 300 units in the output layer mean 300 possibilities for (t+1)th time step and those 300 values are not your output sequence. Hence only 1 unit in the output layer, also Decoder can generate a lesser number of items than 300 even if you give 300 length sequences in all training instances anything between 0 to max_seq_length(i.e 300 in your case)

Comment: But it should work. Just keep 1 unit in the decoder output layer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This worked, I went with 5 layers: 4 LSTM and a dense layers, and trained on 1.5 mm samples.

Comment: Great!!
Number of output units in the last layer?

Comment: just a single 300 dense as the output unit,

Comment: And how are you using these 300 units to arrive at a single value?

Comment: I want 300 outputs, the idea was after 2 months of data (60), can I predict the remaining values of the year. To reiterate input 60 days, output 300 days,